# How do I render sibling elements without wrapping them in a parent tag?

Tags: reactjs

In most cases, having a parent tag isn't an issue.

```
React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        );
    }
});
```

But there are some cases where it makes sense to have sibling elements in one render function without a parent, and especially in the case of a table, you don't want to wrap a table row in a `div`.

```
React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
        );
    }
});
```

The second example gives the following error: `Adjacent XJS elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag while parsing file`.

How can I render two sibling elements without wrapping them in a `<div>` or something similar?

Comment: I always seem to have trouble finding this question/answer so I decided to ask/answer it myself. Additional explanation/answers are welcome.

Comment: Another example is navigational items

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Woohoo! The React team finally added this feature. As of React v16.0, you can do:

```
render() {
  // No need to wrap list items in an extra element!
  return [
    // Don't forget the keys :)
      <tr key="a"><td>Item 1</td></tr>,
      <tr key="b"><td>Item 2</td></tr>
  ];
}
```

See the [full blog post explaining "New render return types: fragments and strings" here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings).

Answer (score 68):

This is a limitation currently, but will likely be fixed at some point in the future ([there's some open issues on the github repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127)).

For now, you can use a function which returns an array (this is basically a stateless component):

```
function things(arg, onWhatever){
    return [
        <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>,
        <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
    ];
}
```

And use that in your component.

```
return (
    <table><tbody>
      {things(arg1, this.handleWhatever)}
      {things(arg2, this.handleWhatever)}
    </tbody></table>
);
```

### Update

In React 16 you will be able to return an array from render.

### Another Update

You can now either return a top level array, or use `<React.Fragment>`.

With an array we need to place a key on each item, as React doesn't know that the two elements are constant, instead of a dynamically created list:

```
function RowPair() {
  return [
    <tr key="first"><td>First</td></tr>,
    <tr key="second"><td>Second</td></tr>,
  ]
}
```

With `React.Fragment`, it behaves much more like wrapping it in a `<div>` or similar, where a `key` isn't required if we're not building the children dynamically. First, we can wrap the array in a Fragment:

```
function RowPair() {
  return <React.Fragment>{[
    <tr key="first"><td>First</td></tr>,
    <tr key="second"><td>Second</td></tr>,
  ]}</React.Fragment>
}
```

And then we can eliminate the array and `key`s entirely:

```
function RowPair() {
  return <React.Fragment>
    <tr><td>First</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Second</td></tr>
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: Why does everyone say this works???? Uncaught Error: x.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: @Xogle Something must have changed in the React API. Doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I see the problem. It's not a "stateless component" it's a function returning an array. Stateless components can't return arrays and you can't connect a simple function to the Redux store.

Comment: @PetrPeller are you using jsx? In the example I'm calling it like a function.

Comment: I don't understand all the upvotes - this doesn't answer the question at all. The question is how to render sibling elements without a parent element and this answer still renders a parent element.

Comment: This answer worked for me, but it did take a few minutes of rejiggering, probably because anyone with this problem is going to have a relatively complex DOM structure.

Comment: My +1 is for the Update - I was not aware of this, and the Array-Solution is the correct answer now :)

Comment: @Syndic thanks for reminding me about this. Updated the answer

Answer (score 36):

I know this has been an old post, but maybe my answer could be a help for newbies like me.

In React 16.2, improved support for **Fragments** was added.

You can now return it like this:

```
return (
  <>
    <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
  </>
);
```

You can wrap it with `<></>` or `<Fragment></Fragment>`.

If you would like to pass some attributes, only **key** is supported at the time of writing, and you'll have to use `<Fragment />` since the short syntax `<></>` doesn't accept attributes.

*Note: If you are going to use the short syntax, [make sure that you are using **Babel 7**](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#babel).*

[Source Reference](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html)

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thanks! Also, just in case anyone else needs it: import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

Comment: I can't seem to find the implementation of `Fragment` in their repository, can someone, please, show me? Thanks :)

Comment: I can't make it work, even if I install Babel-cli... even only for the <> solution. How is it possible @onoya I'll be posting a thread soon,

Answer (score 3):

Having a parent element is helpful in most cases, as for example, you can have a parent **className** which can target children elements style and a few other scenarios...

But, if you really don't want to do that, you can use `React.Fragment`

So simply do something like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <First />
  <Second />
  <Third />
</React.Fragment>
```

From **version 16.2**, there is a shortened version also using `<>`, which look like this in render function:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <First />
      <Second />
      <Third />
    </>
  );
}
```

Also, if using **version 16.0** and above, you can return array of elements which doesn't need parent wrapper also like below:

```
render() {
 return [
  <h1 key="heading">Hello from Alireza!</h1>,
  <p key="first">Here where I'm!</p>,
  <p key="second">And again here :)</p>
 ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can render two sibling components by wrapping them inside `React.Fragment`. For e.g.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
     <Item1/>
     <Item2/>
  </React.Fragment>,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

There is even a shorter hand for this though.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
     <Item1/>
     <Item2/>
  </>,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Wrapping the components inside the `React.Fragment` does not add extra nodes to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it to the brackets like this:

```
React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          [
            <tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
          ]
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: How about if you also need to use ``Object.keys()`` within the return?

Comment: Eg.  ``return ( [ <tr><td>Header</td></tr>{ Object.keys(this.props.data).map(function(item) { <tr><td>{data}</td></tr> }) } ] );``

With 15.4.2, it gives ``Unexpected token, expected ,`` in the opening bracket within the return

Comment: try something like this: return ({ Object.keys(this.props.data).map(function(item) { <tr><td>{data}</td></tr> }).unshift({<tr><td>Header</td></tr>})});

Comment: This does not work, still needs to have a comma separating <tr>-s

Answer (score 0):

This example is work well for me:

```
let values = [];

if (props.Values){
  values = [
    <tr key={1}>
      <td>props.Values[0].SomeValue</td>
    </tr>
  ,
    <tr key={2}>
        <td>props.Values[1].SomeValue</td>
        </tr>
    ];
}

return (
    <table className="no-border-table table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Some text</th>
        </tr>
        {values}
      </tbody>
    </table>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this syntax worked for me

```
this.props.map((data,index)=>{return( [ <tr>....</tr>,<tr>....</tr>];)});
```

Answer (score -2):

For those, who uses TypeScript, the correct syntax is:

```
return [
  (
    <div>Foo</div>
  ),
  (
    <div>Bar</div>
  )
];
```

Comment: This is identical to the answer by @thealexbaron and it has nothing to do with TypeScript